# java - Cannot convert Integer to int

Tags: java

I am stuck at this problem for ages. Basically I cannot convert Integer to int.

```
class CheckOdd implements Check<Integer>
{
  public <Integer> boolean check(Integer num)
  {
    int i = (Integer) num;
    return (i % 2 != 0);
  }
}
```

I have tried using
`int i = (Integer) object;`   `int i = (int) object;`  `intValue()`
but still no luck. If I use `int i = (Integer) object;` it produce `error:incompatible types`.
If I use `int i = (int) object;` it produce `error: inconvertible types`.

Please Help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is a bad practice to write yourself a wrapper around existing wrappers. java.lang.Integer works fine. If you need an integer implementation with more features, I would invite you to rethink your design and naming conventions before really writing yourself a new Integer class.

Comment: @EricTobias, while you are correct, I am not sure that the OP **intentionally** attempts create a wrapper, rather the issue is caused of misused generics.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've replaced `java.lang.Integer` with a generic type which you have named `Integer`

```
public <Integer> boolean check(Integer num) // <-- not a java.lang.Integer
```

should be

```
public boolean check(Integer num)
```

Answer (score 3):

After java 1.5 Autoboxing was supported. So you can use

```
int i = num;
```

Comment: You mention [Autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) but your example is actually the reverse; *Autounboxing*. Also, with OP's generic this would not have worked because `<Integer>` was a generic type (and not `java.lang.Integer`).